# IloEnv is not working

Tags: java, optimization, cplex

I am using Java to solve a series of problems with Cplex. My main goad is to optimise different stances of a model with modified variables and constraints ( and no, I can't modify the main model every time). To do so, I want to use IloEnv, but, this command:

IloEnv env;

is not recognised by Cplex. It gives me the "IloEnv cannot be resolved to a type" error.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

[IloEnv](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refcppcplex/html/classes/IloEnv.html) is only available in the [C++ API](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refcppcplex/html/overview.html), but not the [Java API](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refjavacplex/html/overview-summary.html) (where the memory management details are hidden).

With the Java API, you can just create an [IloCplex](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refjavacplex/html/ilog/cplex/IloCplex.html) for each instance of your model.

It would be well worth your time to look at the [examples](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/homepages/examplescplex.html) that are shipped with CPLEX Optimization Studio. If `COSDIR` is the location where you installed the product, then the examples can be found at `COSDIR/cplex/examples/src/java`.

Comment: Thanks so much. You saved me from further headaches.