# Is it possible to creat an array of Cplex objects or IloModel?

Tags: java, optimization, cplex

I am using Java to solve a series of problems with Cplex. My main goad is to optimise different stances of a model with modified variables and constraints ( and no, I can't modify the main model every time).

My primary approach was to create an array of Cplex objects like this:

```
IloCplex[] model = new IloCplex[10];
IloNumVar[][] X = new IloNumVar[10][5];
for( int i=0;i<10;i++){
   for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
       x[i][j] = ; // something different each time,e.g. different lb&ub
   }
   rng[i] = ;// something different each time on x[i]s
   model[i].add(x[i]);
   model[i].add(rng[i]);
} // end of for loop
// to separate the model from solving procedure, another IloCplex object has been created:
IloCplex newModel = new IloCplex;
for(int  i=0;i<10;i++){
   newModel = model[i];
   newModel.addMinimize(cost(model[i], x[i]));
   newModel.solve()
   if(newModel.solve()){
       //print the answers
   }
   else{
       //print problem not solvable
   }
```

}// end of for loop

Cost is a function getting model and variables and making a function out of it.

So, the algorithm works for the first time (i=0), but, it seems during the solving procedure, it changes all the model[i]s although I tried to separate them. Hence, in next iteration, the problem can't be solve and I get this error:

ilog.cplex.MultipleObjectiveException

I have also tried to use IloEnv to separate the models, but that also didn't work (I asked it as a question in another post: [IloEnv is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48653753/iloenv-is-not-working)).

Anyone had a similar problem? Do you have a better approach? Any thought to solve the problems?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to create an array of `IloCplex` objects. As you've probably guessed, the error you're getting indicates that you're adding more than one objective to the same model. Without seeing all of your code, it's hard to say more.

Here is a working toy example that uses an array of `IloCplex` objects:

```
  IloCplex[] model = new IloCplex[10];
  IloNumVar[][] x = new IloNumVar[10][5];
  IloRange[] rng = new IloRange[10];
  double[] coefs = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 };

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     model[i] = new IloCplex();
     for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        x[i][j] = model[i].numVar(Math.min(i, j), Math.max(i, j));
     rng[i] = model[i].addLe(model[i].scalProd(x[i], coefs), 20.0);
     model[i].add(rng[i]);
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     IloCplex cplex = model[i];
     cplex.addMinimize(cplex.scalProd(x[i], coefs));
     cplex.exportModel(String.format("model%d.lp", i));
     if (cplex.solve()) {
        cplex.output().println("Solution status = " + cplex.getStatus());
        cplex.output().println("Solution value  = " + cplex.getObjValue());
        double[] val = cplex.getValues(x[i]);
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
           cplex.output().printf("Variable %d: Value = %f%n", j, val[j]);
     }
     else {
        cplex.output().println("Failed to solve instance " + i);
     }
     cplex.end();
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I have done almost the same in my code, but the problem I am facing is that  when I create the new IloCplex object (in your code the cplex one), and then I use "addMinimize" on it like you did, all instances (elements) in the "Model" changes as well. Thta's why, the solver can only solve the first iteration, and in next iteration I get the error message. 
Well, when all the elements of the "Model", i.e. Model[i]s are the same, it is natural to get the error, because after first iteration, Model[1] also has objective function which it shouldn't.

Comment: I even tried to export the models (before making the IloCplex object) and importing them in the second loop, but still, after first iteration, all instances of the save files change as well, i.e. I get similar files on my hard drive!
It is really driving me crazy!!!

Comment: The key to solving your problem will be to start with a very small example (like the working example I gave here) and slowly add more logic to it. It sounds like your array of IloCplex objects is referencing only one model. You probably have a bug in the way you create the array initially.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The problem is too big already to rewrite it from scratch. I am thinking, maybe it is because I used IloModeler to create my variables and constraints. My model is object oriented, so, each object, uses other objects created by IloModeler.  
But again, changing the file after it has been created does not make sense to me. In each iteration, I create the model, save it to file, end it and again in next iteration the file from previous iteration changes and I get the error message.